# Using NLog with Identity Server to log to a database

Tags: nlog, identityserver3

Hello i have been searching everywhere for a solution to log to the database using NLog on Identity Server v3, so far i cannot get very far. It seems Identity Server works with many different Loggers. Does this require an NLog.config file?

Comment: You almost always need a nlog.config. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Thanks i did manage to get it working eventually using the NLog.config

Comment: Cool! Maybe post as answer here (and mark it as accepted)

Comment: In my case i made use of NLog.cong file and used the LogProviderExceptionLogger in the IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting namespace. This class enabled me to intercept exceptions when they are thrown and use NLog to log them to a database